# How do I show $f'(a)$ exists if and only if there is a function $\epsilon(x)$ defined on an open interval $I$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a function defined on an open interval $I$ containing $a$. Show $f'(a)$ exists if and only if there is a function $\epsilon (x)$ defined on $I$ such that $$f(x) - f(a) = (x - a)[f'(a) - \epsilon(x)]$$ and $\lim_{x\to a} \epsilon(x) = 0.$

When I tried to do this problem, I think I'm supposed to do something with the definition of a limit? Where $f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$. But I wasn't really sure where to go from there. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is your definition of derivative? This is nothing more than the definition

Comment: For -> this direction, show that the limit is always unique. For <- this direction, divide the both side by $x-a$ and take a limit to $a$.

Comment: Let $\epsilon (x) = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} - f'(a).$ Isn't it true that $\lim_{x\to a}\epsilon (x)=0$?

Comment: Actually, $f'(a)$ exists if and only if there is a function $\epsilon$ defined on $I$ and a constant $\ell$ such that $f(x) - f(a) = (x - a)[\ell - \epsilon(x)]$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \epsilon(x) = 0$. *Then*, it happens that $f'(a)=\ell$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume
$$ f(x)-f(a)=(x-a)(f'(a)-\epsilon(x)) $$
The equality is trivial for $x=a$, and for $x\neq a$ it's equivalent to
$$ f'(a)-\epsilon(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \Leftrightarrow \epsilon(x) = f'(a)-\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} $$
$ \lim_{x\to a} \epsilon(x)=0 $ if and only if
$$ \lim_{x\to a} f'(a)-\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = f'(a)$$

Comment: This is not correct in terms of notation while the idea is there.The last line should read $\lim_{x\to a} [f'(a)-\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}] = \lim_{x\to a} f'(a)-\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a} f'(a) - f'(a) = 0\Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to a} f'(a) = f'(a) \implies f'(a)$ exists iff $\lim_{x\to a} \epsilon(x) = 0$.